# CometD: Process broadcast messages before broadcasting

Tags: java, jetty, cometd

I have a cometd app running inside jetty.  I want to grab incoming broadcasts from clients, then do some processing (involving interacting with the db) and then finish by broadcasting to all subscribers if no errors are encountered.

My initial thought is to do this with an extension, but is there a more appropriate way?

---

Here is my modified attempt based on @sbordet answer:

```
@Inject
private BayeuxServer bayeux;
@Session
private ServerSession serverSession;

    @Listener("/service/*")
    public void handle(ServerSession remote, ServerMessage message) {
        System.out.println("Message received on service: " + message);

        String broadcastChannel = message.getChannel().replace("/service", "");
        System.out.println("bayeux: " + bayeux + " - sending: " + broadcastChannel + " - " + message.getData());
        System.out.println("bayeux.getChannel(broadcastChannel): " + bayeux.getChannel(broadcastChannel));
        bayeux.getChannel(broadcastChannel).publish(serverSession, message.getData());
    }
```

Essentially, I want to listen for all service channels, and do some processing, then publish to the same broadcast channel, less the /service.  So, /service/test becomes /test.

This current returns a null for `bayeux.getChannel(broadcastChannel)`

Answer (score 1):

Because what you describe is a normal message processing inside CometD, don't use [extensions](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_extensions), but [**services**](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_java_server_services).

Extensions should be used for those cases where you want to modify the behavior of the Bayeux protocol that is at the core of CometD.

Services, on the other hand, are a handy way of handling business messages that your application exchanges and therefore ideal for your case.

Comment: When I use `bayeux.getChannel(broadcastChannel));` then `getChannel()` method returns null...

Comment: I am taking the service channel, `/service/test` and then broadcasting over `/test` - that seems to be correct semantics.  But bayeux (injected via Spring) returns null for getChannel('/test')

Comment: `BayeuxServer.getChannel(String)` is to be used when you know a priori that the channel already exist. Otherwise use `BayeuxServer.createChannelIfAbsent(...)`. Read [the documentation](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_java_server_configuration_channels) about how to configure and initialize a channel.